# Как получить информацию по каждой из полученых ссылок BeautifullSoup?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, bs4

Изучая BeautifullSoup4 решил спарсить дививенды по каждой бумаге на сайте Доход.ру

Получилось спарсить все ссылки в переменную "item" в первом блоке кода но не получаеться к каждой из получених ссылок пременить метод из второго блока кода.

Первый блок:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36"
}


url = "https://www.dohod.ru/ik/analytics/dividend"
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
src = req.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")

first_page_urls = soup.find("tbody").find_all("a") 

for item in first_page_urls:
    item = "https://www.dohod.ru/" + item.get("href")
    print(item) <<< тут список всех ссылок.
```

Второй блок:

```
for div_name in item:

    info_block = soup.find("div", class_="main_content")
    div_name = info_block.find("h1")
    print(div_name) <<< тут назнавие эмитента.
```

Как заставить второй блок кода перебирать ссылки по очереди из переменной "item"?

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так. Собираем ссылки в список, потом проходим по списку. Функционал получения и парсинга страницы через `BS` я вынес в отдельную функцию, потому что это код используется несколько раз. Ссылки были неправильные, исправил:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36"
}

def soup_get(url):
    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    src = req.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
    return soup

main_url = "https://www.dohod.ru/ik/analytics/dividend"
soup = soup_get(main_url)
first_page_urls = soup.find("tbody").find_all("a") 

items = []
for item in first_page_urls:
    item = "https://www.dohod.ru/" + item.get("href")
    print(item)
    items.append(item)

for page_url in items:
    soup = soup_get(page_url)
    info_block = soup.find("div", class_="main_content")
    div_name = info_block.find("h1")
    print(div_name)
```

Comment: Спасибо мне все еще не понятно но все работает! "Функцию получения контента вынес в отдельную функцию" это вы про ```def soup_get(url):``` функцию говорите?

Comment: @AlphaObelisk Ну да. Вам же по каждой ссылке опять нужно страницу получить и обработать `BS`, если я правильно понял. Весь код, который повторяется, лучше выносить в отдельную функцию. Я там немного переформулировал, может понятнее будет.

Comment: у меня возник еще вопрос по поводу ```soup = soup_get(url)``` в последнем цикле тут как бы мы снова вызываем функцию которая в самом начале и 'url' там относиться к первой странице с сылками в переменной ```url = "https://www.dohod.ru/ik/analytics/dividend"``` (если я правильно понимаю) так а как же python понимает что ему все же нужно смотреть в список ссылок из списка ```items``` и игнорировать ранее заданую переменную с первой ссылкой?

Comment: Надо было мне по-разному эти все переменные назвать. У функции есть аргументы, она видит тот `url`, который ей в качестве аргумента передан.

Comment: можете привести пример с разными названиями? мне будет понятнее.

Comment: Поменял в коде названия переменных

Comment: "У функции есть аргументы, она видит тот url, который ей в качестве аргумента передан" в моем случае аргумент это ```in items:``` ?

Comment: я вам признателен, новичкам помогаете это стоит уважения. Спасибо!